# Array List wont output. Java Applet

Tags: java, arrays, list, applet, textfield

I have a problem whilst trying to output a word from my array list into a text field on screen. Whenever I run the program and type a couple of words into the inbox field and click the analyse button, nothing gets outputted, any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class SApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {
TextField input,output;
Label label1;
Button b1, b2;
JLabel lbl;
String Word1;
String wordArrayList[];

public void init(){
    label1 = new Label("Please enter your text: ");
    add(label1);
    label1.setBackground(Color.orange);
    label1.setForeground(Color.black);
    input = new TextField(20);
    add(input);
    output = new TextField(20);
    add(output);
    b1 = new Button("Analyze");
    b2 = new Button("Reset");
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    setBackground(Color.orange);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    try{
        String a = null;
        ArrayList<String> wordArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (e.getSource()== b1)
        {       
            Word1 = input.getText();
        for(String word : Word1.split(" ")) {
            wordArrayList.add(word); 
        }

        Iterator<String> word = wordArrayList.iterator();
        if (word.hasNext()) {
//              output.setText(word.next());
//              System.out.println(word.next());
            a += word.next();
        }

        while (word.hasNext()) {
            a += ", " + word.next();

            output.setText(a);
//              System.out.println(a);
        }
        }

        if(e.getSource() == b2)
            input.setText("");
        output.setText("");
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException a){
        lbl.setForeground(Color.red);
        lbl.setText("Invalid Entry!");
    }
}  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here.

```
if(e.getSource() == b2)
    input.setText("");
output.setText("");
```

You probably intended to write this.

```
if(e.getSource() == b2) {
    input.setText("");
    output.setText("");
}
```

But because you left out the curly braces, blanking out `output` happens every time this method runs, not just if the button that triggered the event is `b2`.

Answer (score 4):

Enclose your `if` statements in braces

```
if (e.getSource() == b2) {
   input.setText("");
   output.setText("");
}
```

otherwise the second statement will always be executed in the `ActionListener`